# UITableViewCell clear spacings

Tags: ios, uitableview

I've got an UITableView with clear background color. The cells are made of:

1. bckgrndView - slightly bigger to get spacing betweens cells
2. -> contentView - contains content, set green
3. -> -> label, textview - green too

I set everything in interface builder (backgroundColor -> clear, opaque -> no), expect that i have to repeat 
`cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    cell.opaque = NO;
    cell.backgroundView = nil;`
 in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` or else, background would be white (bug?)

But as soon as i scroll the clear color is gone and the spacing gets green(== same color as textview)
[image: tableviewImg]
[image]

What am I missing?

Comment: what is in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`.?

Comment: see text ;) im setting text values, cell background color to clear, cell opaque to no, cell background to nil, and then adding shadow and round corners

Comment: - (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

Comment: returns 140, same value as set in interface builder for custom cells. background view height is 140, content views height is 110

Comment: so far i noticed, its the inner view, the "contentView" which, i think, gets resized to fit the bckgrndView. But i wasn't able to fix it, any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed it! 
Renaming the inner view differently from "contentView" did it. 
UITableView has a own property named "contentView", so there was the conflict...